# Customised day view with a date slider as column header instead of single day in fullcalendar in Angular

Tags: angular, slider, fullcalendar, custom-view

I would like to make a full calendar in angular which displays a day tab view which shows a date slider as column header. So on clicking the prev next arrows (which I have customised) I need to change the days in the slider like a carousel. Anyway the body time grid view will be displaying the single day alone that is currently selected in the slider.

In a nutshell on clicking the prev next arrows the slider dates should change and the day view also should change as per the current day user clicked on the slider, The slider dates will be filled with dates of a month that can be handled from ts file.

So I checked the custom view option and agenda options. but it is not solving my problem.

Any help is appreciated. Please do check.

[image]

Comment: fullCalendar doesn't support exactly what you want, sorry. You'd have to re-write a lot of the display engine I think.

Comment: @ADyson ok, how can i implement this if so? do i need to create a slider seperately and include as header ? I am really stuck with this . Any single help is appreciated .Please do check. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write fullCalendar so I don't know how it works internally. You'd have to examine the source code and see what needs changing. Either that or you start again from scratch, or find another calendar plugin which is closer to your requirements. Or, lastly, you think about whether your requirement is actually essential or not, or whether the standard next/previous buttons in fullCalendar are actually sufficient to allow users to navigate within the calendar. Your requirement looks simply like some nice-to-have UI - so it wouldn't be high up my priority list for a project.

Comment: ok, thank you@ADyson